# Out of memory in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Here's the problem:
I'm trying to make a small reporting tool. So... I have a MultiPage with about 8-9 pages and on every page there's another Multipage with 2-5 pages. On every page there are 8-10 comboboxes, about 6 textboxes and so on.
It worked well 'till now when I tried to add another 5 pages in the last page to finish the program. Now when I want to compile it it says "Out of memory"
From what I searched on Google it seems that the problem might come from the fact that the main Multipage stores too much stuff and too many controls. Some suggestions I saw were to brake the main Multipage... but I don't know how to design it to seem like a continuation of the main multipage 
Do you guys have any suggestions or do you know if there might be another reason why I get this error? 
Thanks a lot!
https://i.stack.imgur.com/WnHRy.jpg to see the design ...lots of multipages and pages...

Comment: If you've been working on this for a while, you should start by exporting all of your VBA code/form/class modules to files, deleting them from the Excel file, and then re-importing them from the exported files. This often solves issues with large projects, which can suffer from build-up of "cruft" during development.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you try Rob Bovey's Code Cleaner http://www.appspro.com/Utilities/CodeCleaner.htm

And redesign your form into a series of separate forms that follow a logical sequence of choices and requested data. Once the user has made their initial choices you should not need to show them all the rest of your multi-multipage. 
Also try using multiselect Listboxes for multiple choices.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions! I don't have much code so far... I just designed the form... Unfortunately I don't see a better design than this (I have other ideas but those don't solve the problem of having too much stuff in one Control). Through this form the production supervisors in my segment will report the production on every machine (and there are a lot of machines, and about 2-3 different products made on each everyday). Right now they have an excel with a lot of rows and they write everything in them but there are a lot of problems and that's why I want to do this form.

Comment: so build a generic form for 1 machine and then loop reusing it for each machine that is relevant to a supervisor